# Rust implement Into trait for Arc<Bar> to Arc<dyn Foo>

Tags: rust, traits

I'm trying to cast a struct which implements a trait to a trait object of that same trait. The problem is that the trait object needs to wrapped in an `Arc` and I can't implement the `Into` trait for an `Arc`. Due to the following code not compiling:

```
use std::sync::Arc;

trait Foo { }

struct Bar {}

impl Foo for Bar { }

impl Into<Arc<dyn Foo>> for Arc<Bar> {
    fn into(self) -> Arc<dyn Foo> { self }
}

fn bar_to_foo(bar: Arc<Bar>) -> Arc<dyn Foo> {
    bar.into()
}
```

This fails with the following compiler message:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::convert::Into<std::sync::Arc<(dyn Foo + 'static)>>` for type `std::sync::Arc<Bar>`:
 --> src/lib.rs:9:1
  |
9 | impl Into<Arc<dyn Foo>> for Arc<Bar> {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
          - impl<T, U> std::convert::Into<U> for T
            where U: std::convert::From<T>;
  = note: upstream crates may add a new impl of trait `std::convert::From<std::sync::Arc<Bar>>` for type `std::sync::Arc<(dyn Foo + 'static)>` in future versions

error[E0117]: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for arbitrary types
 --> src/lib.rs:9:1
  |
9 | impl Into<Arc<dyn Foo>> for Arc<Bar> {
  | ^^^^^------------------^^^^^--------
  | |    |                      |
  | |    |                      `std::sync::Arc` is not defined in the current crate
  | |    `std::sync::Arc` is not defined in the current crate
  | impl doesn't use only types from inside the current crate
  |
  = note: define and implement a trait or new type instead

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

However I cannot do the following either:

```
use std::sync::Arc;

trait Foo { }

struct Bar {}

impl Foo for Bar { }

impl Into<dyn Foo> for Bar {
    fn into(self) -> dyn Foo { self }
}

fn bar_to_foo(bar: Arc<Bar>) -> Arc<dyn Foo> {
    bar.into()
}
```

Because that results in:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn Foo + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/lib.rs:9:6
  |
9 | impl Into<dyn Foo> for Bar {
  |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn Foo + 'static)`
```

I'm probably missing something obvious, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a moron:

```
use std::sync::Arc;

trait Foo { }

struct Bar {}

impl Foo for Bar { }

fn bar_to_foo(bar: Arc<Bar>) -> Arc<dyn Foo> {
    bar
}
```

I'll show myself out.

Comment: This does not work if I want to accept `Option<Arc<Bar>>` and return `Option<Arc<dyn Foo>>`. Any clue on how to handle this scenario?

Comment: Also, this doesn't work when the implementor is itself a `dyn`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66067777/how-to-upcast-an-rcdyn-foo